# How do I create a subfolder in the Laravel Store

Tags: laravel, storage

I'd like to create a subfolder in storage like
/storage/app/public/user_folder

Does anyone know how to do it with the proper permissions?

Comment: http://php.net/mkdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'm going to assume you want to do it programmatically, perhaps from within a controller?

So lets make use of Laravel's `Filesystem` class to help us do this.

At the top of your controller, lets bring it in like so: `use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;`

Now we can instantiate it. `$file = new Filesystem();`. And I might do it like this:

```
    $file = new Filesystem();
    $username = 'userNameGoesHere';
    $directory = 'directory/goes/here/' . $username;
    if ( $file->isDirectory(storage_path($directory)) )
    {
        return 'Directory already exists';
    }
    else
    {
        $file->makeDirectory(storage_path($directory), 755, true, true);
        return 'Directory has been created!';
    }
```

Now, lets break down what we just did. First, we check if the directory exists. It's just good practice to do this, I think. If not, then we create it.

Lets break down what the arguments for `makeDirectory()` are. First is the system file path. We make use of the `storage_path()` helper that Laravel gives us to point us to the storage directory. Then we pass in the directory. The second argument is the chmod permissions for that directory. By default it is set to `493`. Third, we set the directory creation to be recursive, meaning it will create each directory in your path. Default for recursive is `false`. The final argument tells the directory creation to force it. If you didn't check if the directory exists and attempted to create it anyway without setting this to `true`, Laravel would throw an exception complaining that the directory already exists. If it's set to true Laravel just recreates the directory anyway.

You can read more about the Filesystem class [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply use `mkdir`. Assuming 775 is the proper permission for you:

`mkdir(storage_path('app/public/user_folder'), 0775)`

Comment: Thanks and yeah I needed the 775 permission :) This also works